# Continuation resume not work when App in a background state

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

For example i have construction like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.handleAppLoad() {
     val app = AppFactory.createApp(
                    context = Application.instance.applicationContext
                )

                app.doSmth()

                startActivity(
                    SuccessActivity.createIntent(
                        requireContext()
                    )
                )
}
}
```

In my fragment code, when i clicked on some button.

```
  suspend fun handleAppLoad(
        scope: CoroutineScope = viewModelScope,
        block: suspend () -> Unit
    ) {
        scope.launch {
        progress.value = true
            try {
                delay(1000)
                block()
            } catch (ex: MsalOperationCanceledException) {
                // B2C process was cancelled, do nothing
            } catch (ex: MsalException) {
                _msalErrorEvent.emit(ex)
                Timber.e(ex)
            }
        progress.value = false
        }
    }
```

^ My coroutine wrapper

Also i have this code in AppFactory.

```
object AppFactory {

    suspend fun createApp(
        context: Context
    ): App {
        return suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            App.create(
                context,
                object : IApp.ApplicationCreatedListener {
                    override fun onCreated(application: App) {
                        cont.resume(application)
                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: Exception) {
                        cont.resumeWithException(exception)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the application goes to the background and the callback `cont.resume(application)` works in the background, the coroutine does not stop, but continues to wait for the same `cont.resume(application)`, so that's why my progress stay active, while `cont.resume(application)`already happened. I know a way to fix it by removing the callback->coroutine construction, but I am interested in the way to fix the current version, since the coroutine has a wrapper that controls the progress at the start and end of the coroutine.